# removing music from amazon music playlists - is it really this hard?

Tags: amazon-music

I use Amazon music and have multiple playlists created.  You can quickly find an album or even a playlist and dump it into your "music library" into one of your playlists.  However if you want to remove large numbers of songs from a playlist it is REALLY painstakingly hard work unless I'm missing something.  For example if you want to remove all songs by a particular artist or album how do you do it?  the only way I can see is one by one - imagine if you have 150 or 200 songs to remove - it's sooo tedious.  Anyone have any BKMs?

Comment: This doesn't work. I cant believe how hard it is to do stuff with Amazon Music on a mac. I thought Itunes was bad but this is awful. I cant multiple delete, I can't even clear recents history.

Answer (score 1):

looks like a figured out how to speed the process up, although still not perfect.  Within the Amazon Music App (on PC/Mac) you can actually select multiple songs by holding control/command(Mac) - it wasn't obvious to me on Mac from the UI but turns out it's possible - therefore much easier to select multiple songs one by one and delete them all at once with a right click - rather than having to right click and delete each one individually.